# How to use a resolver for collections in AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, llblgenpro

I want to map some of my domain objects back to ORM (LLBLGen) entities, for this I'm using AutoMapper. The domain objects contain collections, and the AutoMapper documentation states that we don't have to worry about them, just about the types they contain. This isn't always the case...

When trying to map to the collections I'm getting a LLBLGen error stating it's not allowed to Clear the ListSource, and we should use the associated collection. So what happens is that AutoMapper seems to be using the LLBLGen collection *as* a ListSource type, in which LLBLGen has overridden the Clear method(not allowing usage).

Creating a resolver doesn't solve this problem, as the destination collection is read-only, so completely replacing it doesn't work.

What I need is a way to customize the *way* AutoMapper maps collections. This is on the collection level, not type level.

Comment: Something's a little off in your code sample there.  Shouldn't you either a) pass in the destination object to Map or b) assign the result of Map to destination?  Right now nothing is happening to the destination object.

Comment: I must have been asleep :( Sorry for wasting your time...

Comment: But, besides the obvious error, I'm still having a little problem. The LLBLGen collection property is read-only(only getter), so can't be replaced. However, I can Add to this collection, if I would have access to the destination member in the ValueResolver. How can I handle this with AutoMapper?

Comment: I'm realizing this has more to do with LLBLGen having strange collection handling then AutoMapper behaviour. I'm gonna let this question remain unresolved since I don't want to put more time into this. Thanks you for you replies!